# Need Help Adding NTS Version of PHP to WampServer to run ZendLoader

Tags: php, wamp

I'm trying to add a 5.5.38 NTS version of PHP to WampServer 2.5 running on a PC using the instructions on [this website](https://websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp).

As you may know, WampServer 2.5 comes bundled with a thread safe 5.5.12 version of PHP, but I want to run ZendLoader which requires a NTS version.

After adding PHP 5.5.38 and opening the login page of my Web site, I get

> Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\wamp\www\db_connect.php

`php_error.log` contains a PHP Warning for each `.dll` the `php.ini` file tries to load, such as

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.38/ext/php_bz2.dll' - The specified module could not be found. 
>   in Unknown on line 0

And as no surprise the `php_mysqli.dll` is one of them:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.38/ext/php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>   in Unknown on line 0

I've set `extension_dir` in the `php.ini` and `phpForApache.ini` files to:

```
extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.38/ext/"
```

I've verified the path name and that all the .dll files are there.

For some strange reason, `phpinfo()` says I'm still running the thread safe version:

**PHP Version 5.5.12
Thread Safety: enabled**

Even though the WampServer menu shows it as **PHP Version 5.5.38**

When, I exit out of Wampserver through the menu, rename the `php5.5.12` directory to `_php5.5.12` in the `c:\wamp\bin\php` and then try to restart the WampServer, it won't start and I get the following application error:

> Exception Exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000F15AO.
>   Could not execute run action:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

The EventViewer shows:

> Faulting application name: **wampmanager.exe**, version: 1.6.1.33, time stamp: 0x2a425e19
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.16299.402, time stamp: 0x81d25214
>   Exception code: 0x0eedfade
>   Fault offset: 0x00103f12
>   Faulting process id: 0xfa0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d3e9deceef27f0
>   Faulting application path: C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 6f09b108-4472-4d89-8d51-9c69b53100db
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Event ID: 1000
>   Level: Error

It seems to be looking for some file in the 5.5.12 PHP directory I renamed, and I don't know what or why. I'm wondering if this is why WampServer is failing to load the DLL files and why it thinks it's running PHP 5.5.12.

Thoughts on how I can get PHP 5.5.38 NTS working so I can run ZendLoader?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone that viewed this issue.

I discovered the problem is with Apache and that mod_php doesn't support an NTS version of PHP, so I went with FastCGI.

Using the instructions at https://websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp, and the ones at https://commaster.net/content/installing-php-fastcgi-and-zend-opcache-wampserver, I configured Apache and PHP with Zend Guard/Zend Loader and everything is working fine.

Hope this helps anyone else facing this issue.